# jQuery single line code optmization for getting and setting for the same input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I'm using PHPStorm and have the following js code

```
$('#id'.val($('#id'.attr('default'));
```

The idea is to reset the value of a input field to it's default which is set in `default` attribute of the input element.

Now the IDE is suggesting me to avoid duplicate selectors.

Though it is working I'm interested in finding out what is the best way to optimize this code line?

Comment: Storing in an attribute is fine however I prefer to store things like this in the data of the element like `<myelementtag data-defaultvalue='defaultvalue' />` so you could then access it like `$('#myid').data("defaultvalue");`

Comment: Right @MarkSchultheiss and additionally you won't get clashes with HTML6 attributes in the future.

Comment: Yes, then you can do: `var myElement = $('#id'); myElement.value = myElement.data('defaultvalue');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked only one selector and one line code, please use like this as stated in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (middle section):

```
$("#id").val(function(index,value) {
  return $(this).attr('default');
});
```

or if you want to avoid $(this):

```
$("#id").val(function (index, value) {
    return this.getAttribute('default');
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c75b7zp/1/)

And yes, as other members have pointed out, it would be better if you use `data` attribute (`data-defaultValue`) instead.

Comment: I wrote a similar line and strangely that didn't work. Great answer and thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: It seems overkill to me to have a callback to perform such a simple task, remember that function callbacks decrease your code readability. Just my two cents ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for but more future proof using data and not an attribute.  You could even store complex data or other information in there as well like "originalvalue" or "lastchangedvalue" etc.

Storing in an attribute is fine however I prefer to store things like this in the data of the element like:

```
<myelementtag id="myid" data-defaultvalue="defaultvalue" />
```

You then access it like:

```
$('#myid').data("defaultvalue");
```

For example:

```
var myElement = $('#myid'); 
myElement.value = myElement.data('defaultvalue');
```

Want to reset the default?

var mynewdefault = "mynewvalue";
myElement.data('defaultvalue', mynewdefault);

Comment: +one. I personally like your answer and the suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I think the good part of this answer is the suggestion to perform the task without jQuery. It's more readable that way.

Answer (score 1):

Store your jQuery element in a variable:

```
var $id = $('#id');
$id.val($id.attr('default'));
```

Comment: After you store it in a variable would you not just use it like: id.val(id.attr('default'));   http://jsfiddle.net/ovn9263s/

Comment: @DasBeasto You're right. There's no need to repeat `$(...)`.

Comment: @DasBeasto is correct. `id` is already a jQuery element, wrapping it back into `$(...)` is redundant. (Aside: I tend to name jQuery element variables with a `$` (i.e. `$id`) to make it easier to see what's what, but this is totally personal preference.)

Comment: @Shai Nice advise, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a more compact solution:

```
var id = $('#id'); 
id.val(id.attr('default'));
```

You really don't need to use `$(...)` every time.

Comment: Wanted this in one line.